# In Windows, what's the difference between 2<&1 and 2>&1?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

The examples and explanations in this page are leaving me confused:

http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true

Is there any practical difference between using 2<&1 and 2>&1? The second form (2>&1) is familiar to me, from working with the Unix shell.

The page linked above has:

> To find File.txt, and then redirect handle 1 (that is, STDOUT) and handle 2 (that is, STDERR) to the Search.txt, type:
>   findfile file.txt>search.txt 2<&1

and also

> To redirect all of the output, including handle 2 (that is, STDERR), from the ipconfig command to handle 1 (that is, STDOUT), and then redirect the ouput to Output.log, type:
>   ipconfig.exe>>output.log 2>&1

In the end, is there any difference in the results?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Some examples should show what happens:

```
c:\YourDir> cd FolderNotHere > nul
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

You get the error stream

```
c:\YourDir>cd FolderNotHere > nul  2>&1
```

You get nothing, the error stream goes to the std output stream which goes to null.

```
c:\YourDir>cd > nul
```

You get nothing,  the output stream goes to null.

```
c:\YourDir>cd > nul 1>&2
c:\YourDir
```

You get the std outout which has been sent to the error stream so it doesn't get redirected.

```
c:\YourDir>cd > nul 1<&2
```

This seams to do the same as 1>&2

Comment: So it does look like 2<&1 and 2>&1 do the same thing, as i suspected.

Comment: Excuse me. In `cd > nul 1>&2`, the `> nul` part mean "Redirect STDOUT to NUL", but the following `1>&2` mean "Forget that! Now redirect STDOUT to STDERR!", so STDOUT appears in the screen? If so, this example is _the same_ as put no redirection at all!

Comment: Yes, that particular example was funny. But to me, the weirdest part is that the "direction" (< or >) doesn't seem to matter - 2<&1 is the same as 2>&1. I don't understand why; yet testing seems to confirm.

Comment: It seems that < (with no number) mean 0<, and > (with no number) mean 1> (the same as >>), but WITH number < or > is the same!

Comment: It would be much more clear if you would just describe what >, <, & and the numbers mean.